# Fill dropdown list from database elements in prestashop module

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.6

Right now I'm developing a module for a prestashop website and I have a dropdown html select that I would like to fill from the database.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the answer by myself a few days after posting the answer, here's how to do it:
Lets say I wanted to load my clients list from the database, in the hook method of the [module].php file I added a smarty variable:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array('clients' => Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT * FROM `clients_table`')));
```

and that would create a smarty variable that is accessible from the module's tpl.

Then the items in the cilent smarty variable can be added to the dropdown list with:

```
<select id="clients">
    {foreach $clients as $client}
        <option value="{$plan['id']}">{$client['name']}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```